# How can I check specific golang net/http error code?

Tags: go, http

```
package main

import "net/http"

func main() {
     req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "http://domain_does_not_exist", nil)
     if err != nil { panic("NewRequest") }
     client := http.Client{ }
     _, err = client.Do(req)
     if err == ???
}
```

I would like to check my GET request for specific error(DNS resolve error). How to accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Package `"errors"` has functions [As](https://pkg.go.dev/errors#As), [Is](https://pkg.go.dev/errors#Is) to unwrap specific error types, and package `"net"` has a [*DNSError](https://pkg.go.dev/net#DNSError) type. So:

```golang
var dnsErr *net.DNSError
if errors.As(err, &dnsErr) {
    ...
}
```