# How do I work out what type of error my error is in go?

Tags: go, error-handling, go-interface

I'm not sure exactly how to phrase this question, and I've seen others ask similar but not really come up with answers (which tells me I'm asking the wrong question, but I'm not sure how else to approach this).

I'm trying to learn some basic Go, and I've come unstuck at the first hurdle.

In my test code, I'm doing a basic http GET to a domain that doesn't exist to trigger a DNS warning. I worked out that err.error() returns a string, so to assert whether it was a DNS error, I used string comparison:

```
resp, err := http.Get(link)
if err != nil {
    if strings.Contains(err.Error(), "no such host") == true {
        return "no such host"
    }
}
```

This is obviously hacky, so I did some googling to see if there is a better way to work out what kind of error was raised, and I found the following SO answer:

[How can I check specific golang net/http error code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64210407/how-can-i-check-specific-golang-net-http-error-code)

> Package "errors" has functions As, Is to unwrap specific error types, and package "net" has a *DNSError type. So:

```
var dnsErr *net.DNSError
if errors.As(err, &dnsErr) {
    ...
}
```

This code works, but I have absolutely zero idea how this conclusion was reached. Below is how I'm approaching trying to understand this, and I'd like to know where I'm going wrong. I understand (vaguely) what .Is() and .As() are doing, but what I don't understand is how to work out what error "type" to provide those functions without guessing or prior knowledge.

I looked at the client.get() documentation [here](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Client.Get) which says:

> Any returned error will be of type *url.Error.

some more googling and I found that I need to cast(?) the error to that type to work with it:

```
urlErr := err.(*url.Error)
```

the *url.Error contains:

```
&url.Error{Op:"Get", URL:"http://doesnotexistkjdfhgsdfsdf.com", Err:(*net.OpError)(0xc00021a2d0)}
```

so I then look at the net.OpError contained in the url.Error:

```
netOpError := urlErr.Err.(*net.OpError)
fmt.Printf("Net Op Error contains: %#v\n", netOpError)
---
Net Op Error contains: &net.OpError{Op:"dial", Net:"tcp", Source:net.Addr(nil), Addr:net.Addr(nil), Err:(*net.DNSError)(0xc0001a0040)}
```

I then do the same thing and "unpack" the net.DNSError contained within net.OpError:

```
dnsError := netOpError.Err.(*net.DNSError)
fmt.Printf("DNSError contains: %#v\n", dnsError)
---
DNSError contains: &net.DNSError{Err:"dial udp 169.254.169.254:53: connect: no route to host", Name:"doesnotexistkjdfhgsdfsdf.com", Server:"169.254.169.254:53", IsTimeout:false, IsTemporary:true, IsNotFound:false}
```

The net.DNSError doesn't "contain" any other errors so to me, this suggests it's the bottom of the chain and the "real" error (or, at least, one I wanted to work with).

Thing is, this is not a viable approach, and I don't understand how we're supposed to approach this. Before the initial SO article I found, I had no idea that net.DNSError is a thing, or that my error could be of that "type".

If you didn't know a particular error type exists, and that a function call could possibly be of that type, how would you know?

I have a very limited understanding of interfaces and types in general in Go, which I'm sure isn't helping here, but to me there seems to be a huge leap between having an error and knowing what kind of error to check it could be. I hope this question makes sense!

Comment: You may check this post: https://go.dev/blog/go1.13-errors

Comment: If you don't know DNSError exists, then why do you care about handling it? You should care about things you know about, and handle the rest in a generic way.

Comment: If the specific error type is relevant for the user of an API, then those different error types should probably be documented, so that the user knows for which types to look and handle them appropriately. That way the error types become part of the API.

Comment: "I don't understand is how to work out what error type to provide those functions without guessing or prior knowledge" - this is what documentation is for. Where error types are relevant, documentation should indicate what type(s) may be returned. But as rustyx pointed out, if you don't know what type an error may be, it's likely not relevant to your application logic.

Answer (score 5):

First, I'd suggest reading this blog post: https://go.dev/blog/go1.13-errors

Short answer to your question: you're correct, to check that a function returns `net.DNSError` and access its internals you can use `errors.As` function:

```golang
rsp, err := http.Get(link)
dnsErr := new(net.DNSError)
if errors.As(err, &dnsErr) {
  // use dnsErr here
}
```

**Update:** conceptually, it's supposed that you know the type of error you can handle: so you either handle some particular error if you can handle it or wrap and return it to upper level. It's a common practice when working with errors/exceptions in other languages too. So my advice: handle only such exceptions that you know how to process. In case of HTTP requests, it's usually http errors with status codes, DNS errors are usually returned to the caller func.

---

This is some details with examples for functions from `errors` package.

You can use `errors.As` and `errrors.Is` from [errors](https://pkg.go.dev/errors) package. For instance, if you have a custom type of error:

```golang
type myError struct {
    code int
}
```

You can check unknown error by reference with `errors.Is()`:

```golang
var fooErr = &myError{1}

func foo() (int, error) {...}

func main() {
    _, err := foo()
    fmt.Printf("is fooErr? %v\n", errors.Is(err, fooErr))
}
```

or if you want to implement custom logic for comparing your errors (e.g. by `code` in this example), you can add `Is` method to your error type:

```golang
func (e *myError) Is(err error) bool {
    as := new(myError)
    // I'll show As method later
    if !errors.As(err, &as) {
        return false
    }
    return e.code == as.code
}
```

Also, `Is` method can "unwrap" your error from wrapper type, e.g. if you want to create a composition of errors, you may add a new struct with `Unwrap` method for that or use `fmt.Errorf` method with `%w` parameter:

```golang
type errWrap struct {
    origin error
}

func (e *errWrap) Unwrap() error {
    return e.origin
}

func (e *errWrap) Error() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("wraps error '%s'", e.origin.Error())
}

var fooErr = &myError{1}

func foo() (int, error) {
    return 0, &errWrap{origin: fooErr}
}

func main() {
    _, err := foo()
    fmt.Printf("err == myError? %v\n", err == fooErr) // false
    fmt.Printf("err is fooErr? %v\n", errors.Is(err, &myError{1})) // true
}
```

Or using `fmt.Errorf`:

```golang
    err := fmt.Errorf("wraps: %w", fooErr)
    fmt.Printf("err == myError? %v\n", err == fooErr) // false
    fmt.Printf("err is fooErr? %v\n", errors.Is(err, &myError{1})) // true
```

Another important method is `errors.As`, it works similar: you either have the exact type of your error to check or you implement `As` method on your error or error is wrapped by another error:

```golang
    err := &myError{1}
    as := new(myError)
    errors.As(err, &as)
    fmt.Printf("code: %v\n", as.code) // code: 1
```

Or with `As` method:

```golang
type anotherError struct {
    anotherCode int
}

func (e *anotherError) Error() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("code: %d", e.anotherCode)
}

func (e *myError) As(target interface{}) bool {
    if out, ok := target.(**anotherError); ok {
        (*out).anotherCode = e.code
        return true
    }
    return false
}

func main() {
    err := &myError{1}
    as := new(anotherError)
    errors.As(err, &as)
    fmt.Printf("code: %v\n", as.anotherCode) // code: 1
}
```

And same for wrapping:

```golang
err := fmt.Errorf("wraps: %w", &myError{1})
as := new(myError)
errors.As(err, &as)
fmt.Printf("code: %v\n", as.code) // code: 1
```

Comment: While a nice introduction to errors in Go, I'm not sure this addresses the question. How is Dan W supposed to figure out that a particular library function can return a net.DNSError without digging down through lots of layers of documentation and/or source code?

Comment: @RichardHuxton that is exactly my frustration/confusion - the documentation for the http package doesn't show this, so how was this conclusion even reached? All of the answers here are variations of "If you don't know then you don't need to know" or "you must already know". Kirill's post is excellent but .Is() and .As() both need prerequisite knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

What does a user do when loading a web-page and the page fails to load? They hit reload. If it keeps failing, the user eventually studies the error message, as it could be one of many reasons:

- DNS error (client)
- `504` gateway error (server)
- `400` (user: bad request)
- `404` (user: not found)
- `401` (user unauthorized)

How the user *reacts* to these errors determines whether to: give-up; try again; or try again in a different manner. Your question began with the `http.Get` errors (not http status codes) - but the same principle applies.

So, what should you do if the request fails? If the `http.Get` is a critical part of a larger task, then the whole task must fail. If the larger task is expensive to run, you may want to retry the `http.Get` ([exponential backup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_backoff) retry etc.) before failing. Network errors are typically logged as there's very little policy decisions one can make to determine if a retry will work or not (client DNS vs. server `504`).

In a REST-API server implementation, for example, the authentication middleware will return errors for login issues. Here is where the type of error is important and how one can react to it:

- authentication-DB is down

  - server: log full error; email admin etc.
  - client: receives terse `501` (service unavailable)
- invalid credentials

  - server: log full error
  - client: receives terse `401` (unauthorized)

the client is only given a very brief summary that the operation failed, but the server logs the full details of the error and will react to it (alert admin, email user of locked out account or even a successful login, but from an unrecognized device).